# Проблема с неприводимым многочленом шифра Кузнечик

Tags: шифрование, гост

В ГОСТ 34.12-2015 написано, что все операции сложения производятся по модулю многочлена `x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x + 1`. В двоичной форме это `111000011`, т.е. 9 бит.
Что если при каком-то шаге линейного преобразования в результате получится число также состоящее из 9 бит, но которое меньше `111000011`, например, `100100011`? Куда деть старшую единицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно воспринимаете бинарные многочлены, которые применяются в криптографии. `100100011` (`x⁸+x⁵+x+1`) не меньше `111000011` (`x⁸+x⁷+x⁶+x+1`), и не больше.

В конкретно вашем примере, что бы получить остаток от деления одного многочлена на второй, мы просто делаем `xor` побитово:

```
111000011
100100011
---------
011100000
```

И получается:

```
(x⁸+x⁷+x⁶+x+1) mod (x⁸+x⁵+x+1) = (x⁷+x⁶+x⁵)
```